# Pandas groupby custom aggregate calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I have below dataframe which has `country wise orders data` of **last 2 weeks**. I wanted to calculate **% change(increase or decrease) of food orders** compared to last week on grouping by country, start_date and end_date.

[image]

`Formula = (this_week_orders*100)/(last_week_orders) - 100`

For the above df, I want to get the final data frame as following

As we can see, `Russia had a decrease in order count of 33%` and `India had an increase of 50%` compared to last week

[image]

**Please suggest how to write custom aggregation function as I am only familiar with standard one's like sum() , count() etc...**

Comment: @Chris I did `df = df.pct_change(periods=2, axis=1)` but its throwing an error `*** TypeError: cannot perform __truediv__ with this index type: DatetimeIndex
` Please suggest where did I go wrong?

Comment: Can you edit your post to have the actual data, not pictures of the data.  Would make it easier to copy/paste and help find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start_date':['2020-09-21','2020-09-21','2020-09-28', '2020-09-28'], 
                   'end_date':['2020-09-27', '2020-09-27', '2020-10-04', '2020-10-04'],
                  'Country':['Russia', 'India','Russia','India'], 
                   'orders':[150,80,100,120]})
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])

df.sort_values(by='start_date', inplace=True)

df['% Change'] = df.groupby('Country')['orders'].pct_change()
```

Output

```
    start_date    end_date  Country orders  % Change
0   2020-09-21  2020-09-27  Russia  150          NaN
1   2020-09-21  2020-09-27  India   80           NaN
2   2020-09-28  2020-10-04  Russia  100    -0.333333
3   2020-09-28  2020-10-04  India   120     0.500000
```

Comment: I was about to post the original data. Thank you so much chris for the quick help. Its working like a charm